# Gluing of hybrid trajectories in Floer homology

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, moduli-spaces, symplectic-topology, floer-homology

In the paper by A. Abbondadolo and M.Schwarz, *"On the Floer homology of cotangent bundles"* [arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408280), to prove the desired isomorphism between the Floer homology and the Morse homology of the Lagrangian one looks at the hybrid moduli space problem. Recently I have been trying to understand how one can obtain the gluing of the trajectories on these moduli spaces to prove that we have a chain map between the Floer and Morse complexes.

There are two types of broken trajectories that can happen, either coming from the Morse-type problem or the Floer-type problem as explained in Proposition $3.6$. Let's for now focus on the Floer one which is Proposition $3.9$ part b. The authors claim that the gluing here works as in classical Floer theory, however in this case I belive that for $u\in \mathcal{M}^{+}(q,x_0)$ and $v\in \mathcal{M}(x_0,x_1)$ I belive the pre-gluing as to be something of the form

\begin{cases}
      u(s,t) & s\leq \rho-1 \\
      \exp_{x_0(t)}(\beta_{}^{-}(s-\rho)\exp_{x_0(t)}^{-1}(u(s,t))+\beta^{+}(s-\rho)\exp_{x_0(t)}^{-1}(v(s-2\rho,t))) & |s-\rho|\leq 1\\
      v(s-2\rho,t) & s\geq \rho+1
   \end{cases}

So that we have the desired boundary conditions regarding the moduli space $\mathcal{M}^{+}(q,x_1)$.  However this is slightly different from what I find in the literature, as per example in the book Morse theory and Floer homology, therefore I am having some trouble proving that the gluing map, which is then constructed using a version of the Newton-Picard Method, is an embedding. Mainly because the derivative of this pre-gluing operation seems to be tricky, and I haven't quite figured it out.

Therefore I was wondering if anyone knows of any reference in the literature of gluing in hybrid-moduli spaces problem that would resemble something like this?

Any insight is appreciated, thanks in advance.